# objective-c variable declaration inside { } vs outside of @interface & @end

Tags: objective-c, ios

Please can any one tell me whats the difference between declaring a variable inside { } vs outside of @interface & @end in header file. Both ways lead to successful compilation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want the variable to be part of the class (a.k.a. instance variable) then you declare it inside the brackets, otherwise it is declared as a global variable which has nothing to do with the class.

e.g.

```
// XYZ.h

@interface XYZ
{
  int myinstancevariable;
}
@end

int myglobalvariable;
```

...

```
XYZ* a = [[XYZ alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%d", [a myinstancevariable]);
NSLog(@"%d", myglobalvariable );
```

edit: forgot {}

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but now Xcode do not by default include { } ?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a variable inside a `code block - {}` it's scope (lifespan) is inside that block only.

If you declare it outside `@interface` & `@end` it's scope is inside that file. If this would be a header file this variable could be used globally.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but now Xcode do not by default include { } ?

Comment: @rokjarc: The scope of a variable within the ivar {} block is the class (I think that was what you meant but it's a little misleading to say that it's just within the block). Sweet Jenny: That's probably because Apple now encourages the use of properties instead of bare instance variables.

Comment: Yes, i guess i misunderstood the question a bit. First part of answer goes for variables inside code blocks (that are inside methods) and the other part goes for variables outside all code-blocks and also outside the @interface 'block'.