# Xcode duplicate symbol error for sample project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6.3

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

CGFloat screen;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

I have just created a sample Xcode project and declared a variable at the top of AppDelegate.h. It is giving me duplicate symbols error, and I have done that many times in previous projects, it worked fine. I have tried in another mac and it is working fine. Does anyone knows how to resolve this.

Note: I am getting this error, since I have upgraded Xcode to 6.3,I have tried in 3 systems two of them have upgraded to 6.3 and I am getting same error, but in one system it is still 6.2 and it is working fine. The Screen variable is giving me errors. I have used these kind of variables in my previous projects which were approved by App store.

Comment: Die you clean the project? Use `cmd` + `shift` + `k`.

Comment: @LinusG. I have tried cleaning the project ,many times, I have tried deleting the derived data and module cache.

Comment: Can you please post that variable declaration?

Comment: Use `extern CGFloat screen;` in `AppDelegate.h` and add this line `CGFloat screen;` in `AppDelegate.m` file.

Comment: @KudoCC Thanks, it works, but why it is working in some projects created using pervious Xcode version.. Is there any bug or update in new versoin

Comment: @BalaChandra It must be you didn't import the AppDelegate.h in other files in those projects.

Comment: This happened me as well, and adding 'extern' before my declarations fixed it. Again, only started happening on Xcode 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're defining `screen` as a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10975838/225503) (not as an instance variable). You have defined `screen` outside AppDelegate class, so now it is defined in a broader scope.

Maybe you've also defined screen in your `AppDelegate.h` file?

If not, use the search navigator to find out if you *really* have this symbol duplicated in your Project / Workspace

[image: search navigator in Xcode]